# Facebook iOS SDK: What needs to be in the appdelegate

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the new facebook sdk into my app. My question is, do all of the fbsession methods have to be called from the app delegate, or only those which require leaving the app (ie signing in via safari for those who don't have the fb app?)

I've tried calling requests directly from view controllers via :

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForGraphPath: ...
```

and it seemed to return without problems, but I just wanted to make sure that that would always be the case before I went about doing that in more places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to call fb related calls from app delegate. you can call them from any class you like. you should have fb ios sdk configured correctly before.

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of the Facebook sdk quite painful. In the beginning (facebook earlier versions) you would need to make the calls from the `UIAppDelegate`, although now you can use it from whatever place you want. I would also recommend something to ease your pain: https://github.com/mobitar/Zuckerkit.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to take a look at that package seems like it has a lot of useful stuff.

Comment: I did a small Gist as well for retrieving the user picture: https://gist.github.com/RuiAAPeres/6383419

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Guarav mentioned, FB calls can take place from anywhere within your iOS code.

If you have successfully added the Facebook SDK to your project, and you need to access FBSession from more than one place in your app, it may be helpful to add the FacebookSDK.h header reference within your pre-compiled header (.pch):

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
    ... (etc.)
#endif
```

The .pch header file is typically found in the "Supporting Files" group in your project.